# How to understand that whole message was received for uart port?

Tags: c++, linux, select, serial-port, protocols

I've got a two controllers one with uclinux, second without any os. They are connected by serial port. I check that new message received with `select` function. Message length might be different and controller without os sends message per bytes. So, there is a possibility that one controller does not send whole message and `select` function returns that new message is available. After that I will receive incorrect message.
How I can prevent this situation?

Comment: Are you really using C++ on a microcontroller, or is it C?

Comment: I use c++ on dsp processor and c on a microcontroller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `select` function will only tell you that you can read *at least* one byte without blocking. The message sent on the serial port needs to either have a predefined header that contains the total length of the message, or a special end-of-message marker.

When `select` says you can read, you read as many bytes as you can and put them in a buffer. If the message is not complete you go back to wait for more data with `select`. When more data arrives you continue append to the buffer. When a complete message is received you process it.